# Restangular how to test if an Rest-Resource is reachable

Tags: angularjs, restangular

If have an Rest-Resource which can be down. In my App I will do a put to the Resource but before the put is performed I see an OPTIONS-Request which get an Error and the put is not performed. So I can not handle the error state of the put. How can I check that an Resource is not reachable? Or how can I disable the OPTIONS-Request? Or how can I interact with the OPTIONS-Request, to get the error from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Options requests is for CORS request. The browser does a OPTIONS requests to see if the current method is allowed in the request type. This is the way CORS works. You can handle your error in your promise and check the error code to handle it appropriately. If you want to do it across your app try a interceptor.

http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/ (PS I am the author of the article. shameless plug)

Comment: Hi thx for answer. I know that the Browser makes the OPTIONS-Request, but if this request fails the error message in the then promise ist not invoiked. I think this is because the put-request is not send from the browser, he knows that it would fail.

Comment: That is pretty strange. The options should actually call the failed promise.

Comment: Did the Option call the fail promise if no network connection is reachable?

Comment: Same issue with me , $http sends a OPTIONS-Request first and if the server is not reachable it throws the error in console as "OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:300/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and Status = 0 in .error(function